# Android-Studio: How to make a resource string value the same as its name

Tags: android, android-studio, resources

I want to use the string resources to save some key values. So, I have something like this:

```
<string name="key_name">key_name</string>
```

The resource name and the resource value are the same. There is no need for me to make a difference between them, as it is just to cleanly store one value.

To reduce redundant information, 
is there a way to just tell android-studio that the name equals the value? Something like this?

```
<string name="key_name"/>
```

Comment: This **Key-Value** pair was born with XML and this is how it is designed purposely.

Comment: if you just want key_name only then you can just declare variable, xml is key-value pair. like  <string name="api_token">toreduceredundantinformationisthereawaytojusttellandroidstudio</string>

Comment: @shizhen Im aware of that, but all the information needed to implement  behaviour like that is there, so it would be neat if its possible.

Comment: You have to respect the fact of xml tool

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can't do it. It looks like you create a variable, you must name it and when you need you can set its value.
You can't create a variable with same values with name at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have the wrong resource type. A `string` resource is used for mapping a name to a text. From what you're describing here you only need the name (and then can extrapolate the text from it).

Using strings with matching name and value shouldn't be necessary:

- If you're going to be referencing them from Java or Kotlin code, you still need to know the name (i.e. `R.string.key_name`), so you might as well just use the string value there.
- If it's for using inside XML code (where you want to pass the value of a string, e.g. `text="@string/key_name"`) most of the time you can just use the raw string there (i.e. `text="key_name"`).

Comment: I want to use it in java code, but I already thought that this is not possible. Thought I might ask anyway and maybe get lucky.

Comment: I'm just wondering - if you have to write in Java "R.string.key_name" why not just write "key_name"? Perhaps a string array would make more sense?

Comment: No. I just want to have one value to use it as an identifyer for something. I want to have it in one place to keep my code clean, as this identifier is used multiple times. An array would not make sense, because then I would have to remember the index for that element.